# How to implement MKClusterAnnotations in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am trying to make cluster views for annotations that are really close to each other on my Apple Map. I know Apple has native cluster view kit came out with iOS 11, but all tutorials I could find online are written in Swift. I hope somebody could teach me or recommand me any tutorials that i could read to find out how to implement clustered annotations in Objective-C.

My idea is to create a ClusterView class, which inherits the MKAnnotationView class, and then create a instance of the ClusterView in the mapView controller.

I have read the documentation from apple, it only provides you with functions that I might need to call, but it didn't explain how to use them, this is the link to Apple Documentation:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkclusterannotation?language=objc

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the basic steps:

1. Define your annotation view, specifying `clusteringIdentifier` and `collisionMode`:

   ```
   //  CustomAnnotationView.h

   @import MapKit;

   @interface CustomAnnotationView : MKMarkerAnnotationView

   @end
   ```

   and

   ```
   //  CustomAnnotationView.m

   #import "CustomAnnotationView.h"

   static NSString *identifier = @"com.domain.clusteringIdentifier";

   @implementation CustomAnnotationView

   - (instancetype)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
       if ((self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
           self.clusteringIdentifier = identifier;
           self.collisionMode = MKAnnotationViewCollisionModeCircle;
       }

       return self;
   }

   - (void)setAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
       [super setAnnotation:annotation];

       self.clusteringIdentifier = identifier;
   }

   @end
   ```
2. Optionally, if you want, you can define your own cluster annotation view, specifying `displayPriority` and `collisionMode`. This one also updates the image for the cluster to indicate how many annotations are clustered:

   ```
   //  ClusterAnnotationView.h

   @import MapKit;

   @interface ClusterAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView

   @end
   ```

   and

   ```
   //  ClusterAnnotationView.m

   #import "ClusterAnnotationView.h"

   @implementation ClusterAnnotationView

   - (instancetype)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
       if ((self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
           self.displayPriority = MKFeatureDisplayPriorityDefaultHigh;
           self.collisionMode = MKAnnotationViewCollisionModeCircle;
       }

       return self;
   }

   - (void)setAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
       super.annotation = annotation;
       [self updateImage:annotation];
   }

   - (void)updateImage:(MKClusterAnnotation *)cluster {
       if (!cluster) {
           self.image = nil;
           return;
       }

       CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
       UIGraphicsImageRenderer *renderer = [[UIGraphicsImageRenderer alloc] initWithSize:rect.size];
       self.image = [renderer imageWithActions:^(UIGraphicsImageRendererContext * _Nonnull rendererContext) {
           // circle

           [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
           [[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];

           UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];
           path.lineWidth = 0.5;
           [path fill];
           [path stroke];

           // count

           NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long) cluster.memberAnnotations.count];
           NSDictionary<NSAttributedStringKey, id> *attributes = @{
               NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle: UIFontTextStyleBody],
               NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]
                                                                   };
           CGSize size = [text sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
           CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width  - size.width)  / 2,
                                        rect.origin.y + (rect.size.height - size.height) / 2,
                                        size.width,
                                        size.height);
           [text drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:attributes];
       }];
   }

   @end
   ```

   You don’t have to create your own subclass for the cluster if you don’t want to. But this just illustrates how you can completely control the appearance of the cluster, should you choose to do so.
3. Then your view controller just needs to register the appropriate classes and you’re done (no map view delegate needed):

   ```
   [self.mapView registerClass:[CustomAnnotationView class] forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier];
   ```

   If you want to use your custom clustering view, you can register that, too:

   ```
   [self.mapView registerClass:[ClusterAnnotationView class] forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier];
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   //  ViewController.m

   #import “ViewController.h"

   @import MapKit;

   #import "CustomAnnotationView.h"
   #import "ClusterAnnotationView.h"

   @interface ViewController ()
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
   @end

   @implementation ViewController

   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       [self configureMapView];
   }

   - (void)configureMapView {
       self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow;

       [self.mapView registerClass:[CustomAnnotationView class] forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier];
       [self.mapView registerClass:[ClusterAnnotationView class] forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier];
   }

   // I’m going to search for restaurants and add annotations for those,
   // but do whatever you want

   - (void)performSearch {
       MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
       request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"restaurant";
       request.region = self.mapView.region;

       MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
       [search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
           if (error) {
               NSLog(@"%@", error);
               return;
           }

           for (MKMapItem *mapItem in response.mapItems) {
               MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
               annotation.coordinate = mapItem.placemark.coordinate;
               annotation.title = mapItem.name;
               annotation.subtitle = mapItem.placemark.thoroughfare;
               [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
           }
       }];
   }

   @end
   ```

That yields:

[image: demo]

Comment: See sample project at https://github.com/robertmryan/MapKitClusteringObjC.

Comment: thank you so much for your comment, it is very helpful

Comment: I searched all Google for iOS 17 SwiftUI Map() but nothing. Some people advice using QuadTree and some are DBSCAN algorithms. Algorithms part is okay, but I'm not able to update Map using that algorithms. @Rob, do you have any example code for using that clustering mechanism in SwiftUI Map()?

Comment: I don't see any clustering support in SwiftUI `Map`. You may have to create `UIViewRepresentable` or `UIViewControllerRepresentable` with `MKMapView` to leverage these clustering abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example as simple as couple of steps

1) Add following annotations within `viewDidLoad` will work just fine

```
MKPointAnnotation *point1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D c1;
c1.latitude = 46.469391;
c1.longitude = 30.740883;
point1.coordinate = c1;
point1.title = @"Minsk, Belarus";
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point1];

MKPointAnnotation *point2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D c2;
c2.latitude = 46.469391;
c2.longitude = 30.740883;
point2.coordinate = c2;
point2.title = @"Odessa, Ukraine";
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point2];
```

2) Within mapView:viewForAnnotation of MKMapViewDelegate provide reusable view for annotations, like so:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]]) {

        MKMarkerAnnotationView* annotationView = (MKMarkerAnnotationView *) (MKMarkerAnnotationView *)[_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"Jacky.S"];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKMarkerAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Jacky.S"];
            annotationView.enabled = YES;
            annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = @"pins";
            // annotationView.glyphImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"we can use a nice image instead of the default pins"];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
            annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = @"pins";
        }
        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Do not forget to set `MKMapViewDelegate` to `UIViewController`

```
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];
```

**Update** Just finished posting a [gist](https://gist.github.com/r-aamir/4d2fbc7c2d3f98682a57212b4543111b) shows how to subclass `MKMarkerAnnotationView`